# why don't Hive have FIELDS ENCLOSED BY like in MySQL?

Tags: hadoop, hive

here is my case :

input lines:

```
"vijay" <\t> "a-b-c","a-c-d","a-d-c" 

"kumar" <\t> "a-b-c","b-c-d""
```

i created table like this :

```
hive >create table user_infos(name string, path ARRAY<String>  --i need array only)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' COLLECTION ITEMS 
TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STORED AS TEXTFILE ;
```

output received :

```
hive > select * from user_infos ;

"vijay"       ["**\"a-b-c\"**","**\"a-c-d\"**","**\"a-d-c\"**"]

"kumar"       ["**\"a-b-c\"**","**\"b-c-d\"**"]
```

problem here is :  i don't want double quotes i.e., **\"**

Required output :

```
vijay   ["a-b-c","a-c-d","a-d-c"]  

kumar   ["a-b-c","b-c-d"]
```

Is there any why to  achieve this not using **custom Serde**. Any thing like ENCLOSED BY like in mysql?

Comment: These quotes show up in real results?  As in, somewhere besides a REPL?

Comment: In hive shell (hive>) which is a REPL, when i executed the select, i am getting the double quotes. i want to avoid them.

Comment: + edited the Question clearly

Answer (score 2):

I was also stuck with the same issue as my fields are enclosed with double quotes and separated by semicolon(;). My table name is employee1.

So I have searched with links and I have found perfect solution for this.

@ramisetty.vijay: Yes, We have to use serde for this. Please download serde jar using this link : https://github.com/downloads/IllyaYalovyy/csv-serde/csv-serde-0.9.1.jar

then follow below steps using hive prompt :

```
add jar path/to/csv-serde.jar;

create table employee1(id string, name string, addr string)
row format serde 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde'
with serdeproperties(
"separatorChar" = "\;",
"quoteChar" = "\"")
stored as textfile
;
```

and then load data from your given path using below query:

```
load data local inpath 'path/xyz.csv' into table employee1;
```

and then run :

```
select * from employee1;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your ans, but my data is not of csv-input