# Upload .csv data in Hive which is in enclosed format

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive

My .csv file is in an enclosed format.

```
    "13","9827259163","0","D","2"
    "13","9827961481","0","D","2"
    "13","9827202228","0","A","2"
    "13","9827529897","0","A","2"
    "13","9827700249","0","A","2"
    "12","9883219029","0","A","2"
    "17","9861065312","0","A","2"
    "17","9861220761","0","D","2"
    "13","9827438384","0","A","2"
    "13","9827336733","0","D","2"
    "13","9827380905","0","D","2"
    "13","9827115358","0","D","2"
    "17","9861475884","0","D","2"
    "17","9861511646","0","D","2"
    "17","9861310397","0","D","2"
    "13","9827035035","0","A","2"
    "13","9827304969","0","D","2"
    "13","9827355786","0","A","2"
    "13","9827702373","0","A","2"
```

Like it is in mysql, I have tried using "enclosed" keyword as follows..

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dnd (ServiceAreaCode varchar(50), PhoneNumber varchar(15), Preferences varchar(15), Opstype varchar(15), PhoneType varchar(10))
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
LOCATION '/dnd';
```

But, it is giving an error as follows...

```
NoViableAltException(26@[1704:103: ( tableRowFormatMapKeysIdentifier )?])
    at org.antlr.runtime.DFA.noViableAlt(DFA.java:158)
    at org.antlr.runtime.DFA.predict(DFA.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.rowFormatDelimited(HiveParser.java:30427)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.tableRowFormat(HiveParser.java:30662)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.createTableStatement(HiveParser.java:4683)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.ddlStatement(HiveParser.java:2144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:1398)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1036)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:975)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1040)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:911)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:901)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:268)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:220)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:359)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processReader(CliDriver.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processFile(CliDriver.java:466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:748)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:686)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:625)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
FAILED: ParseException line 5:33 cannot recognize input near 'ENCLOSED' 'BY' ''"'' in serde properties specification
```

Is there a way I can directly import this file ?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Find another way. The solution is serde. Please download serde jar using this link : https://github.com/downloads/IllyaYalovyy/csv-serde/csv-serde-0.9.1.jar

then follow below steps using hive prompt :

```
add jar path/to/csv-serde.jar;

create table dnd (ServiceAreaCode varchar(50), PhoneNumber varchar(15), Preferences varchar(15), Opstype varchar(15), PhoneType varchar(10))
row format serde 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde'
with serdeproperties(
"separatorChar" = "\,",
"quoteChar" = "\"")
stored as textfile
;
```

and then load data from your given path using below query:

load data local inpath 'path/xyz.csv' into table dnd;
and then run :

```
select * from dnd;
```

Comment: No. Its also giving the same error..

FAILED: ParseException line 5:33 cannot recognize input near 'ENCLOSED' 'BY' ''\\"'' in serde properties specification

Comment: use single back slash, instead of double.

Comment: Try the new solution "Serde", given in the above answer

Comment: I tried it.. The table name that I have kept is "dxm". When the .hive is executed, there is no problem. But, when I execute  "select * from dxm limit 10;" I get the following execption
FAILED: RuntimeException MetaException(message:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Class com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde not found)

I have tried searching the internet using this error, to no avail. Do you know how I cab avert it ?

Answer (score 1):

> Hey I did it quoted csv data in hive table:
>   first download csv serde(I downloaded csv-serde-1.1.2.jar)
>   Then

```
hive>add jar /opt/hive-1.1.1/lib/csv-serde-1.1.2.jar;
Hive>create table t1(schema) row format serde 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde' with serdeproperties ("separatorChar" = ",") LOCATION '/user/hive/warehouse/dwb/ot1/';
```

> Then we have to add serde in the hive-site.xml as below mentioned, so that we can query table from hive-shell.

```
<property><name>hive.aux.jars.path</name><value>hdfs://master-ip:54310/hive-serde/csv-serde-1.1.2.jar</value></property>
```

Answer (score 0):

In hive we can use jar file to retrieve the data which is enclosed in double quotes.

For your problem please refer this link :

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21156071/why-dont-hive-have-fields-enclosed-by-like-in-mysql
```